# Empty $_controllerDirectory array (from Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard) during phpunittest

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework

I am trying run phpUnitTest (3.5.4) with Zend_Framework (v 1.10.8) and still receive

```
Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application
```

for example test of class AuthControllerTest which extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase

```
/**  * @test  */ public function
loginPage() {

  $this->dispatch('/login');
  $this->assertController('auth');
  $this->assertAction('login'); }
```

After debug I found that variable $_controllerDirectory in Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard is empty. Normally it contains:

> array   'Default' => string
>   'C:\x\phpcode\application/modules\Default\controllers'

I have defined router

```
 <loginPage>
     <route>login</route>
     <defaults>
         <module>default</module>
         <controller>auth</controller>
         <action>login</action>
     </defaults>
     <map>
     </map>
     <reverse>login</reverse>
 </loginPage>
```

and other FC params

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://www.fff44.pl:8080/"
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

do you use zend_application?

my solution:

```
protected function _setUp ()
{
    // your Zend_Application instance from your own test-bootstrap file
    $application = Zend_Registry::get('application');

    if ($this->bootstrap === null) {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application (
            $application->getEnvironment(),
            $application->getOptionsFile(),
            $application->getDefaultsFile()
        );
    }

    parent::_setUp();
}
```